# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'authService' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, mybatis

When trying to use the api, I get this error:

```
"org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'authService' available".
```

How do I make the authservice be found by the app? I've gotten a similar error before, which I tried to fix by adding all the packages you see below in the Main class.

The Main class:

```
package com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.lvwangbeta.poplar.action.PoplarActionServiceApplication;
import com.lvwangbeta.poplar.feed.PoplarFeedServiceApplication;
import com.lvwangbeta.poplar.tag.PoplarTagServiceApplication;
import com.lvwangbeta.poplar.user.PoplarUserServiceApplication;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.lvwangbeta.poplar.common","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.common.intr","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.action",
        "com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api.service",
        "com.lvwangbeta.poplar.feed","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.tag",
        "com.lvwangbeta.poplar.user", "com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api"})
//@ComponentScan({"com.lvwangbeta.poplar.common","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.user","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.feed.dao", "com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api"})
@ComponentScan({"com.lvwangbeta.poplar.action.dao.impl","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.feed.dao.impl"})
@MapperScan({"com.lvwangbeta.poplar.action.dao","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.feed.dao","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.tag.dao"})
public class PoplarApiApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Object[] sources = {PoplarApiApplication.class,PoplarTagServiceApplication.class};
        //SpringApplication.run(sources, args);
        System.out.println("Started");
        SpringApplication.run(PoplarApiApplication.class, args);
        //SpringApplication.run(PoplarTagServiceApplication.class, args);//I hope this works
        //SpringApplication.run(PoplarActionServiceApplication.class, args);
        //SpringApplication.run(PoplarFeedServiceApplication.class, args);
        //SpringApplication.run(PoplarUserServiceApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        argumentResolvers.add(new RequestAttributeArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
        registry.addInterceptor(new APIAccessAuthRequiredInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/api/v1/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/api/v1/user/login/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/api/v1/user/check/email/*")
                .excludePathPatterns("/api/v1/user/register/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/api/v1/feed/of/user/**");
    }
}
```

The AuthService class:

```
package com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api.service;

import com.lvwangbeta.poplar.common.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.HashOperations;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Service("authService")
public class AuthService {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Resource(name="redisTemplate")
    private HashOperations<String, String, Object> mapOps;

    public User getUserByToken(String token) {
        return (User) mapOps.get("tokens:", token);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? It's not registering even though the api link is there. I'm trying to combine many microservices to one, and so there's alot of packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include `com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api.service` in `@ComponentScan`

Like this :

```java
@ComponentScan({"com.lvwangbeta.poplar.action.dao.impl","com.lvwangbeta.poplar.feed.dao.impl", "com.lvwangbeta.poplar.api.service"})
```

**Suggestion** :For simple applications avoid configuring the way above.

Keep your project structure as explained in this reference and `@SpringBootApplication` is enough.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Comment: That seemed to fix it, but I'm only getting error 404's. My response is "{"timestamp":"2020-06-07T06:18:40.586+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/v1/user/check/email/Email@email.com"}". Do you happen to know why this is?

Comment: /api/v1/user/check/email/{email}  -  do you have this API ?

Comment: I added some more packages to component scan and also added the usercontroller basepackageclass and that seemed to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: updated answer for recommended approach and check this article for to understand componentscan - https://dzone.com/articles/spring-spring-boot-and-component-scan